# C++ lambda pointer/reference memory occupation struggle

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, reference, pass-by-reference

I've decided to start **learning** C++ lately; coming from scripting background (Ruby, JavaScript, PHP). I've started building a very simple *observer*. What I am trying to achieve, is a custom callback for `notify` method as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<class StateT>
class Observer{

    typedef function<void(StateT)> LambdaT;

    LambdaT callback;

    ~Observer(){
        //delete callback;
    };

public:

    void setCallback(LambdaT &callback)
    {
        this->callback = callback;
    };

    void notify(StateT state){
      this->callback(state);
    };


};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Observer<string>* obs = new Observer<string>;

    std::function<void(string)> customCallback = [](string state){
        cout << state << endl;
    };

    obs->setCallback(customCallback);

    obs->notify("State has changed");

    return 0;
}
```

Then I have a `Subject` to observe, and when `Subject` instance is being destroyed, all of it's attached observers are being destroyed too, in order to free memory. This was just an idea, which could be wrong in terms of "ideal" implementation, also not sure if that's how I am supposed to clean memory, I haven't tried smart pointers yet.

```
~Subject(){
    for(listIterator......){
        delete (*it); //observer instances pointers are stored in a list
    }

};
```

I was planning to pass **callback** for my observer, as a pointer to `setCallback()` function, so i can delete it as I delete observer instances from subject. Now my main question is how do I de-allocate memory, which has been occupied by my callback (which is now an observer property)?

Comment: Another thing is that when i create lambda, when passing it as an function argument, it becomes temporary object (? not sure), and therefore i cannot refference it. Meaning that lambda is somehow scoped to my observer already? My point here is knowing, when my created lambdas are freed from memmory :)

Comment: `Observer<string>* obs = new Observer<string>;` unnecessary. Just use `Observer<string> obs;`

Comment: Why? I'll be deleting that observer at some point

Comment: I didn't notice you are deleting it in Subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The callback property is not dynamically allocated. You only need to make sure to deallocate your observer. As a rule of thumb, there should be one `delete` for each `new`. Since you never use new for a LambdaT, then there is no need for delete.

Since the `setCallback` method takes a reference to your callback, this method sees the same value as your main method. But, you do not store a reference to the callback, you store a copy of the callback. So to make this clear:

- `customCallback` is the original value.
- `callback` is a reference to `customCallback`.
- `Observer::callback` is a copy of `callback`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, are you saying that by the moment i deallocate my observer, it's callback property will be gone as well. That makes absolute sense as it's an object property. 

Wouldn't it be smarter (less memmory occupation), if I've created a lambda pointer, then pointed it to my lambda, and passed that to function? Or is there any smarter way (pointer-like) of achieving that?

Comment: Not necessarily. Usually, you should try to keep dynamic allocation to a minimum. Only use them when you really need to. With move constructors, copying data is not as big of a problem as before in C++ so in this case, it could be considered as a premature optimization. If you really wanted to pass it dynamically, then you should use smart pointers (probably a `std::shared_ptr` in this case).

Comment: Good point, should i store a & in Observer::callback? probably yes. 
I've seen std::function<>::target in c++ refference, but so far i was unable to implement that, would you mind showing us an example of getting a function pointer via std::function<>::target? (if that's even possible, i might be completely mistaken)

Comment: Storing references is very dangerous. Lets say you make the `Observer::callback` property a reference, can you tell just by looking at the code which value will be stored there? Will it be the memory location of the original `customCallback` or will it be the location of the `callback` method parameter? Honestly, I see no use for target unless you want to high-jack the "this" parameter inside a lambda like you would do with `bind` in JavaScript. Even then, since we are not in JS and the scoping rules actually makes sense, it probably means that you are doing something very wrong in your code.

Comment: Original goal was to store memmory location of firstly created lambda function (in main) as a callback prpperty for my observer,  so i can use it without passing it around as a value, copying it in memory.

Comment: Have you actually looked at how big an `std::function<void(std::string)>` is? On a 64bit machine, I would expect it to be about 32 bytes, maybe less. Passing it around as a pointer would drive it down to 8 bytes. The problem here is that modern x64 processor have enough registers to pass a 32byte value to a function call without having to push it in memory. This makes the call almost instantaneous. Passing it as a pointer would require you to dereference its value every time you need to use it. This would require memory accesses which are terribly slow. In other words, premature optimization.

Comment: This was the answer i was looking for, thanks. Lesson learned